ASP.NET Core y Sweet Alert2
Estoy aprendiendo a usar ASP.NET Core y para practicar me puse a programar un proyecto ficticio:
cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int id)
{
   return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
}

HTML
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Descripcion</th>
                        <th>Activa</th>
                        <th>Creada el</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if (Model.appList != null && Model.appList.Any())
                    {
                        @foreach (var item in Model.appList)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/ApiManagement/Applications/Edit?id=@item.application_id"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm alert_delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                                    
                                
                                </td>
                                <td>@item.application_name</td>
                                <td>@item.description</td>
                                <td>@(item.is_active ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
                                <td>@item.created_at</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5">Sin resultados</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".alert_delete").click(function () {
            var appId = $(this).data("id"); // Obtén el ID de la aplicación a eliminar

            Swal.fire({
                title: '¿Estás seguro?',
                text: "¡No podrás revertir esto!",
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Sí, eliminar!',
                cancelButtonText: 'No, cancelar'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    console.log("ID to delete:", appId);
                    // Realiza la llamada AJAX para eliminar el registro usando el appId
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Page("/ApiManagement/Applications", new { handler = "OnPostDeleteAsync" })', // URL del handler Delete en Razor Page
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // Envía datos como clave-valor
                        data: { id: appId }, // Envía el ID como parámetro
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response.success) {
                                Swal.fire(
                                    '¡Eliminado!',
                                    'La información ha sido eliminada.',
                                    'success'
                                ).then(() => {
                                    location.reload(); // Recarga la página después de la eliminación
                                });
                            } else {
                                Swal.fire(
                                    'Error',
                                    response.message || 'No se pudo eliminar la aplicación.',
                                    'error'
                                );
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            console.log("XHR Status: ", status);
                            console.log("XHR Error: ", error);
                            console.log("XHR Full Response: ", xhr); // Esto te muestra todo el objeto XHR

                            Swal.fire(
                                'Error',
                                'No se pudo eliminar la aplicación.',
                                'error'
                            );
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

El problema que tengo es que al aceptar la eliminación recibo un http code 400 en la respuesta, sin detalle de que pudo haber fallado y sin llegar a ejecutar OnPostDeleteAsync.
Me gustaria pedir ayuda ya sea para que la misma pantalla en donde tengo listado los registros ejecute el delete o bien, si debo implementar el delete desde algún otro componente y luego volver a la pantalla del listado para mostrar respuesta de éxito.
De antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Revisando tu codigo me parece que el error se presenta a la hora de generar la consulta, la URL que indicaste no es la correcta, estás usando una sintaxis propia de razor @Url.Page("/ApiManagement/Applications", new { handler = "OnPostDeleteAsync" }) para hacer la consulta, en este caso deberías de generar la url de manera correcta, por ejemplo, puedes crear la siguiente función en tu layoud o bien, dentro de tu vista:
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseUrl = "@Url.Content("~/")";
    function resolveUrl(url) {
       if (url.indexOf("~/") === 0) {
          url = baseUrl + url.substring(2);
       }
       return url;
    }
</script>

y posteriormente, general la url de esta forma:
url: resolveUrl("/ApiManagement/Applications/OnPostDeleteAsync"), // URL del handler Delete en Razor Page
type: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // Envía datos como clave-valor
data: { id: appId },

Espero que esto te sea de ayuda.
Saludos.
